# Using python to counts occurrence of each adjacent character

Tags: python

Use Python to solve this question：
Define a function that takes a string, counts each adjacent occurrence of a character. This function should return a string with each character and its count. For example:

'jjjjeerrr' would return to 'j4e2r3'

Comment: where is the work done so far?

Answer (score 0):

The `zip()` function is your friend when you need to compare elements of a string or list with their successor or predecessor.  With that you can get the indexes of the first letter in each repeated sequence.  These "break" positions can then be combined (using zip again) to form start/end ranges that will give you the size of the repetition:

```
def rle(S):
    breaks = [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(S,S[1:]),1) if a!=b]
    return "".join(f"{S[s]}{e-s}" for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[len(S)]))
```

Output:

```
print(rle("jjjjeerrr"))      # j4e2r3
print(rle("jjjjeerrrsssjj")) # j4e2r3s3j2
```